# OAuth token generation process in class library

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an existing application developed in traditional ASP.Net code behind, currently, we have a custom token generation process. So basically aspx.cs invoking class library which contains the token generation logic and returning to aspx.cs file. Now the requirement is implementing OAuth token-based authentication using the same structure.

I have gone through lot of articles and everything is in Web API. But my requirement is how can I do the OAuth token-based authentication using the C# class library. Please help me how to do that. Step by step guidance will be better for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from token generation, what other features are available from the class library? You just need to use those feature from aspx code behind and allow or deny the user access.

Comment: These class libraries are basically holding the business logic (Validating the user credentials, creating the token using custom logic and saving the token to DB), allow or deny access is done from another class library. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You need to call appropriate methods on the class library from the aspx.cs code or custom http handlers. What's the exact issue you are facing? Can you share relevant code of whatever you have tried and explain where are you stuck and what do you expect to be done?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Actually I have not tried anything yet. I was just wondering that there is some endpoint of OAuth token generation (access token, refresh token, etc) and all are web API based. How can I put that token generation process into class library method so that by invoking that method all the token related information will be generated maintaining the OAuth standards and return it to aspx.cs code for further process. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: You just need to move the token generation logic to a different class and call method of that class. This is the starting point and then progress step by step. Why don't you start with this?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ok let me start with this. Hope this will work. Thanks.

Comment: ~Why does everyone assume that we're always working in web-based projects? What about Windows Desktop apps, console apps, etc, etc, etc...?